# Using output status of VerifyElementPresent in Selenium IDE on chrom

Tags: selenium-ide

I am using Seleium IDE on chrome. I want to make a simple code using the output of "VerifyElementPresent" command. If the output is true, execute code1 else execute code2.

I cannot find a way to store the output of this command in a variable so I can use it further.

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no information in documentation about storing result of ['verify element present' command](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands/#verify-element-present). But you can use ['store xpath count'](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands/#store-xpath-count) for this reason.

```
store xpath count | xpath=some_xpath | n
if | ${n} > 0 |
code1...
else | |
code2...
end | |
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your answer but it didn't work for me.
store xpath count | xpath = //*[@id="plhMain_lblMsg"] | X

Error: 
storeXpathCount on xpath = //*[@id="plhMain_lblMsg"] with value X Failed:
09:32:11
Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression xpath = //*[@id="plhMain_lblMsg"] because of the following error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.

Comment: @Ashebl 'Target' field is filled wrongly. You should delete spaces like this: xpath=//*[@id="plhMain_lblMsg"]